# JSP is called twice via Ajax /a href?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a JSP1 with a link that calls function (Ajax) to pass variable to another JSP2. It looks like jsp2 is getting loaded twice. Any idea why?

My app console log:

```
my_id = 77An2J
my_id = null
```

JSP1 code:

```
<a href="#" onClick="list_edit('<%=request.getAttribute("id")%>');return false;">Edit List</a>
```

JSP2 has the following code:

```
String my_id = request.getParameter("id");
System.out.println("my_id = " + id);
```

jQuery:

```
function list_edit(id) { 
    ajax_redirect('/jsp2.jsp', { id: id }); 
  }

  function ajax_redirect(url, data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        complete:
        function() {
            window.location = url;
        }
    });
  }
```

**EDIT** So, technically I'm trying to achieve the following:
1) Servlet reads URL, parses ID, loads data from DB based on ID and prints results on the screen. Here I'm also displaying "Edit List" link

2) Clicking "Edit List" link has to send variables from servlet to JSP2 and also load JSP2 in the browser

I'm stuck on the step 2. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First call to JSP2 is in ajax post call, but second call is in this instruction `window.location = url;` and in this case you don't pass ID, so in log *null* is displayed.

Comment: True, but if I remove `window.location = url;` ajax call is not loading my URL in browser...

Comment: Don't use ajax and do it synchronously.